# Run PHP on Android App

Tags: php, android

I'm trying to make a simple Android App that displays a simple string on screen from a php script on an actual url. Unfortunately I keep getting this classic message "Unfortunately, Hello has stopped" after trying lots of ways of doing this.

This is myActivity.java:

```
package com.example.scoelli.hello;

import ...


public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    TextView txtHelloWorld;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);


        txtHelloWorld = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txthelloworld);
        new ConnectTask().execute();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class ConnectTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, HttpResponse> {
        protected HttpResponse doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String url = "http://www.scoelli.ewwoconsulting.com/hello/";
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            try {
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet(new URI(url));
                request.addHeader("User-Agent", "Android");
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
                return response;
            }catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException ioe){
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(HttpResponse result) {
            String resultado = "NOO";
            StatusLine statusLine = result.getStatusLine();
            try {
                if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    result.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                    out.close();
                    resultado = out.toString();
                }
            } catch (IOException ioe){
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
            txtHelloWorld.setText(resultado);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my PHP script:

```
<?php
namespace Controller;

Class Hello
{
    static function World()
    {
        echo "Hola Mundo!";
    }
}
?>
```

I have a controller which calls the static function World; I know the php works.

I don't know if changes anything but I'm using Android Studio.

This is the Logcat:

```
...
07-02 15:54:28.532      381-629/? I/PackageManager﹕ Action: "android.intent.action.SENDTO"
07-02 15:54:28.532      381-629/? I/PackageManager﹕ Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
07-02 15:54:28.532      381-629/? I/PackageManager﹕ Adding preferred activity ComponentInfo{com.android.mms/com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity} for user 0 :
07-02 15:54:28.542      381-629/? I/PackageManager﹕ Scheme: "sms"
07-02 15:54:28.592      381-385/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 1072K, 16% free 6185K/7344K, paused 49ms+9ms, total 216ms
07-02 15:54:28.592      381-629/? D/dalvikvm﹕ WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 49ms
07-02 15:54:28.672      381-392/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Delay finish: com.android.keychain/.KeyChainBroadcastReceiver
07-02 15:54:28.712      381-614/? I/PackageManager﹕ Action: "android.intent.action.SENDTO"
07-02 15:54:28.712      381-614/? I/PackageManager﹕ Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
07-02 15:54:28.712      381-614/? I/PackageManager﹕ Adding preferred activity ComponentInfo{com.android.mms/com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity} for user 0 :
07-02 15:54:28.722      381-614/? I/PackageManager﹕ Scheme: "smsto"
07-02 15:54:28.772      381-613/? I/PackageManager﹕ Action: "android.intent.action.SENDTO"
07-02 15:54:28.772      381-613/? I/PackageManager﹕ Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
07-02 15:54:28.772      381-613/? I/PackageManager﹕ Scheme: "mms"
07-02 15:54:28.772      381-613/? I/PackageManager﹕ Adding preferred activity ComponentInfo{com.android.mms/com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity} for user 0 :
07-02 15:54:28.822      381-560/? I/PackageManager﹕ Action: "android.intent.action.SENDTO"
07-02 15:54:28.822      381-560/? I/PackageManager﹕ Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
07-02 15:54:28.822      381-560/? I/PackageManager﹕ Adding preferred activity ComponentInfo{com.android.mms/com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity} for user 0 :
07-02 15:54:28.832      381-560/? I/PackageManager﹕ Scheme: "mmsto"
07-02 15:54:28.912      517-526/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 394K, 15% free 3338K/3924K, paused 25ms+4ms, total 102ms
07-02 15:54:28.932      517-517/? D/dalvikvm﹕ WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 22ms
07-02 15:54:29.122      381-628/? I/PackageManager﹕ Adding preferred activity ComponentInfo{com.android.mms/com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity} for user 0 :
07-02 15:54:29.132      381-628/? I/PackageManager﹕ Action: "android.intent.action.SENDTO"
07-02 15:54:29.142      381-628/? I/PackageManager﹕ Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
07-02 15:54:29.142      381-628/? I/PackageManager﹕ Scheme: "sms"
07-02 15:54:29.192      381-410/? I/InputReader﹕ Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
07-02 15:54:29.222      381-561/? I/PackageManager﹕ Adding preferred activity ComponentInfo{com.android.mms/com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity} for user 0 :
07-02 15:54:29.232      381-561/? I/PackageManager﹕ Action: "android.intent.action.SENDTO"
07-02 15:54:29.232      381-561/? I/PackageManager﹕ Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
07-02 15:54:29.232      381-561/? I/PackageManager﹕ Scheme: "smsto"
07-02 15:54:29.242      381-381/? D/BackupManagerService﹕ Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.example.scoelli.hello flg=0x4000010 (has extras) }
07-02 15:54:29.252      381-381/? V/BackupManagerService﹕ removePackageParticipantsLocked: uid=10052 #1
07-02 15:54:29.292      381-381/? V/BackupManagerService﹕ addPackageParticipantsLocked: #1
07-02 15:54:29.342      381-629/? I/PackageManager﹕ Action: "android.intent.action.SENDTO"
07-02 15:54:29.342      381-629/? I/PackageManager﹕ Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
07-02 15:54:29.342      381-629/? I/PackageManager﹕ Scheme: "mms"
07-02 15:54:29.342      381-629/? I/PackageManager﹕ Adding preferred activity ComponentInfo{com.android.mms/com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity} for user 0 :
07-02 15:54:29.452      381-626/? I/PackageManager﹕ Action: "android.intent.action.SENDTO"
07-02 15:54:29.452      381-626/? I/PackageManager﹕ Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
07-02 15:54:29.452      381-626/? I/PackageManager﹕ Scheme: "mmsto"
07-02 15:54:29.452      381-626/? I/PackageManager﹕ Adding preferred activity ComponentInfo{com.android.mms/com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity} for user 0 :
07-02 15:54:29.552      381-613/? I/PackageManager﹕ Action: "android.intent.action.SENDTO"
07-02 15:54:29.552      381-613/? I/PackageManager﹕ Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
07-02 15:54:29.552      381-613/? I/PackageManager﹕ Adding preferred activity ComponentInfo{com.android.mms/com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity} for user 0 :
07-02 15:54:29.562      381-613/? I/PackageManager﹕ Scheme: "sms"
07-02 15:54:29.722      381-385/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 887K, 16% free 6173K/7344K, paused 27ms+8ms, total 253ms
07-02 15:54:29.722      381-613/? D/dalvikvm﹕ WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 162ms
07-02 15:54:29.872      517-517/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 396K, 15% free 3336K/3924K, paused 90ms, total 91ms
07-02 15:54:29.922      381-614/? I/PackageManager﹕ Action: "android.intent.action.SENDTO"
07-02 15:54:29.922      381-614/? I/PackageManager﹕ Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
07-02 15:54:29.922      381-614/? I/PackageManager﹕ Adding preferred activity ComponentInfo{com.android.mms/com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity} for user 0 :
07-02 15:54:29.932      381-614/? I/PackageManager﹕ Scheme: "smsto"
07-02 15:54:30.002      381-625/? I/PackageManager﹕ Action: "android.intent.action.SENDTO"
07-02 15:54:30.002      381-625/? I/PackageManager﹕ Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
07-02 15:54:30.002      381-625/? I/PackageManager﹕ Scheme: "mms"
07-02 15:54:30.002      381-625/? I/PackageManager﹕ Adding preferred activity ComponentInfo{com.android.mms/com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity} for user 0 :
07-02 15:54:30.042      517-526/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 91K, 15% free 3343K/3924K, paused 21ms+13ms, total 167ms
07-02 15:54:30.112      381-393/? I/PackageManager﹕ Action: "android.intent.action.SENDTO"
07-02 15:54:30.112      381-393/? I/PackageManager﹕ Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
07-02 15:54:30.112      381-393/? I/PackageManager﹕ Scheme: "mmsto"
07-02 15:54:30.112      381-393/? I/PackageManager﹕ Adding preferred activity ComponentInfo{com.android.mms/com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity} for user 0 :
07-02 15:54:30.222      381-632/? I/PackageManager﹕ Adding preferred activity ComponentInfo{com.android.mms/com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity} for user 0 :
07-02 15:54:30.232      381-632/? I/PackageManager﹕ Action: "android.intent.action.SENDTO"
07-02 15:54:30.232      381-632/? I/PackageManager﹕ Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
07-02 15:54:30.232      381-632/? I/PackageManager﹕ Scheme: "sms"
07-02 15:54:30.292      381-613/? I/PackageManager﹕ Action: "android.intent.action.SENDTO"
07-02 15:54:30.292      381-613/? I/PackageManager﹕ Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
07-02 15:54:30.292      381-613/? I/PackageManager﹕ Scheme: "smsto"
07-02 15:54:30.292      381-613/? I/PackageManager﹕ Adding preferred activity ComponentInfo{com.android.mms/com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity} for user 0 :
07-02 15:54:30.352      381-551/? I/PackageManager﹕ Action: "android.intent.action.SENDTO"
07-02 15:54:30.352      381-551/? I/PackageManager﹕ Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
07-02 15:54:30.352      381-551/? I/PackageManager﹕ Scheme: "mms"
07-02 15:54:30.352      381-551/? I/PackageManager﹕ Adding preferred activity ComponentInfo{com.android.mms/com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity} for user 0 :
07-02 15:54:30.362      381-673/? D/LightsService﹕ Excessive delay setting light: 695ms
07-02 15:54:30.442      381-393/? I/PackageManager﹕ Action: "android.intent.action.SENDTO"
07-02 15:54:30.442      381-393/? I/PackageManager﹕ Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
07-02 15:54:30.442      381-393/? I/PackageManager﹕ Adding preferred activity ComponentInfo{com.android.mms/com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity} for user 0 :
07-02 15:54:30.452      381-393/? I/PackageManager﹕ Scheme: "mmsto"
07-02 15:54:30.572      517-517/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 412K, 16% free 3331K/3924K, paused 79ms, total 80ms
07-02 15:54:30.612      381-613/? I/PackageManager﹕ Adding preferred activity ComponentInfo{com.android.mms/com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity} for user 0 :
07-02 15:54:30.622      381-613/? I/PackageManager﹕ Action: "android.intent.action.SENDTO"
07-02 15:54:30.622      381-613/? I/PackageManager﹕ Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
07-02 15:54:30.622      381-613/? I/PackageManager﹕ Scheme: "sms"
07-02 15:54:30.712      517-526/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 49K, 14% free 3413K/3924K, paused 23ms+32ms, total 138ms
07-02 15:54:30.722      381-554/? I/PackageManager﹕ Action: "android.intent.action.SENDTO"
07-02 15:54:30.722      381-554/? I/PackageManager﹕ Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
07-02 15:54:30.722      381-554/? I/PackageManager﹕ Adding preferred activity ComponentInfo{com.android.mms/com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity} for user 0 :
07-02 15:54:30.732      381-554/? I/PackageManager﹕ Scheme: "smsto"
07-02 15:54:30.792      381-673/? D/LightsService﹕ Excessive delay setting light: 422ms
07-02 15:54:30.832      381-554/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 897K, 17% free 6148K/7344K, paused 96ms, total 97ms
07-02 15:54:30.922      381-467/? I/PackageManager﹕ Action: "android.intent.action.SENDTO"
07-02 15:54:30.922      381-467/? I/PackageManager﹕ Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
07-02 15:54:30.922      381-467/? I/PackageManager﹕ Scheme: "mms"
07-02 15:54:30.922      381-467/? I/PackageManager﹕ Adding preferred activity ComponentInfo{com.android.mms/com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity} for user 0 :
07-02 15:54:31.032      381-628/? I/PackageManager﹕ Action: "android.intent.action.SENDTO"
07-02 15:54:31.032      381-628/? I/PackageManager﹕ Category: "android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
07-02 15:54:31.032      381-628/? I/PackageManager﹕ Scheme: "mmsto"
07-02 15:54:31.032      381-628/? I/PackageManager﹕ Adding preferred activity ComponentInfo{com.android.mms/com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity} for user 0 :
07-02 15:54:31.072      381-385/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 216K, 16% free 6188K/7344K, paused 20ms+20ms, total 238ms
07-02 15:54:31.072      381-397/? D/dalvikvm﹕ WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 1413ms
07-02 15:54:31.162      536-536/? I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 117 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-02 15:54:31.372      381-541/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Resuming delayed broadcast
07-02 15:54:31.422      381-410/? I/InputReader﹕ Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
07-02 15:54:31.772      536-542/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 423K, 42% free 4894K/8328K, paused 13ms+10ms, total 83ms
07-02 15:54:32.132      381-404/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_EXPLICIT freed 168K, 16% free 6169K/7344K, paused 63ms+20ms, total 713ms
07-02 15:54:32.172    1671-1671/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
07-02 15:54:32.212    1671-1675/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 95K, 16% free 560K/660K, paused 1ms+2ms, total 25ms
07-02 15:54:32.312      381-397/? W/RecognitionManagerService﹕ no available voice recognition services found for user 0
07-02 15:54:33.082    1686-1686/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
07-02 15:54:33.092    1686-1686/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ CheckJNI is ON
07-02 15:54:33.182    1686-1686/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
07-02 15:54:33.202    1686-1686/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
07-02 15:54:33.222    1686-1686/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
07-02 15:54:33.222    1686-1686/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
07-02 15:54:33.222    1686-1686/? D/dalvikvm﹕ No JNI_OnLoad found in libnativehelper.so 0x0, skipping init
07-02 15:54:33.472    1686-1686/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 179 unimplemented (abstract) methods
07-02 15:54:34.222    1686-1686/? E/memtrack﹕ Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
07-02 15:54:34.222    1686-1686/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ failed to load memtrack module: -2
07-02 15:54:34.592    1686-1686/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
07-02 15:54:34.682      381-393/? I/ActivityManager﹕ START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.scoelli.hello/.MyActivity} from pid 1686
07-02 15:54:34.762        49-78/? E/gralloc_goldfish﹕ gralloc_alloc: Mismatched usage flags: 343 x 201, usage 333
07-02 15:54:34.762        49-78/? W/GraphicBufferAllocator﹕ alloc(343, 201, 1, 00000333, ...) failed -22 (Invalid argument)
07-02 15:54:34.762        49-78/? E/﹕ GraphicBufferAlloc::createGraphicBuffer(w=343, h=201) failed (Invalid argument), handle=0x0
07-02 15:54:34.772      381-393/? E/BufferQueue﹕ [ScreenshotClient] dequeueBuffer: SurfaceComposer::createGraphicBuffer failed
07-02 15:54:34.772      381-393/? W/WindowManager﹕ Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (343x201) to layer 21005
07-02 15:54:34.802    1686-1686/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
07-02 15:54:34.862    1686-1690/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 96K, 15% free 586K/684K, paused 1ms+2ms, total 23ms
07-02 15:54:34.922      381-560/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Start proc com.example.scoelli.hello for activity com.example.scoelli.hello/.MyActivity: pid=1696 uid=10052 gids={50052, 3003}
07-02 15:54:34.982    1696-1696/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
07-02 15:54:36.342    1696-1696/? D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8ef1e38, tid 1696
07-02 15:54:36.472    1696-1696/? W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-02 15:54:36.472    1696-1696/? D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
07-02 15:54:36.722      536-536/? I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-02 15:54:36.772      381-395/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Displayed com.example.scoelli.hello/.MyActivity: +1s972ms
07-02 15:54:37.352    1696-1709/? W/System.err﹕ java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "www.scoelli.ewwoconsulting.com": No address associated with hostname
07-02 15:54:37.372    1696-1709/? W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:424)
07-02 15:54:37.372    1696-1709/? W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
07-02 15:54:37.372    1696-1709/? W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
07-02 15:54:37.372    1696-1709/? W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
07-02 15:54:37.402    1696-1700/? D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 183K, 9% free 2915K/3172K, paused 5ms+3ms, total 79ms
07-02 15:54:37.412    1696-1709/? W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
07-02 15:54:37.412    1696-1709/? W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
07-02 15:54:37.412    1696-1709/? W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
07-02 15:54:37.412    1696-1709/? W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
07-02 15:54:37.412    1696-1709/? W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
07-02 15:54:37.412    1696-1709/? W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
07-02 15:54:37.412    1696-1709/? W/System.err﹕ at com.example.scoelli.hello.MyActivity$ConnectTask.doInBackground(MyActivity.java:132)
07-02 15:54:37.412    1696-1709/? W/System.err﹕ at com.example.scoelli.hello.MyActivity$ConnectTask.doInBackground(MyActivity.java:125)
07-02 15:54:37.412    1696-1709/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
07-02 15:54:37.412    1696-1709/? W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
07-02 15:54:37.412    1696-1709/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
07-02 15:54:37.412    1696-1709/? W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
07-02 15:54:37.432    1696-1709/? W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
07-02 15:54:37.432    1696-1709/? W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
07-02 15:54:37.442    1696-1709/? W/System.err﹕ Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
07-02 15:54:37.442    1696-1709/? W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
07-02 15:54:37.442    1696-1709/? W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:61)
07-02 15:54:37.452    1696-1709/? W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405)
07-02 15:54:37.452    1696-1709/? W/System.err﹕ ... 17 more
07-02 15:54:37.452    1696-1696/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
07-02 15:54:37.452    1696-1696/? W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2a71ba8)
07-02 15:54:37.472    1696-1696/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.scoelli.hello, PID: 1696
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.scoelli.hello.MyActivity$ConnectTask.onPostExecute(MyActivity.java:144)
        at com.example.scoelli.hello.MyActivity$ConnectTask.onPostExecute(MyActivity.java:125)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-02 15:54:37.502      381-551/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity com.example.scoelli.hello/.MyActivity
07-02 15:54:37.532       49-122/? E/gralloc_goldfish﹕ gralloc_alloc: Mismatched usage flags: 343 x 201, usage 333
07-02 15:54:37.532       49-122/? W/GraphicBufferAllocator﹕ alloc(343, 201, 1, 00000333, ...) failed -22 (Invalid argument)
07-02 15:54:37.532       49-122/? E/﹕ GraphicBufferAlloc::createGraphicBuffer(w=343, h=201) failed (Invalid argument), handle=0x0
07-02 15:54:37.542      381-551/? E/BufferQueue﹕ [ScreenshotClient] dequeueBuffer: SurfaceComposer::createGraphicBuffer failed
07-02 15:54:37.542      381-551/? W/WindowManager﹕ Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (343x201) to layer 21010
07-02 15:54:38.052      381-396/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{b2f080d8 u0 com.example.scoelli.hello/.MyActivity t14 f}
07-02 15:54:38.472      536-536/? W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-02 15:54:40.402    1696-1696/? I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 1696 SIG: 9
07-02 15:54:40.452      381-426/? E/SoundPool﹕ error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-02 15:54:40.452      381-426/? W/AudioService﹕ Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-02 15:54:40.452      381-426/? E/SoundPool﹕ error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-02 15:54:40.462      381-426/? W/AudioService﹕ Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-02 15:54:40.462      381-426/? E/SoundPool﹕ error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-02 15:54:40.462      381-426/? W/AudioService﹕ Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-02 15:54:40.472      381-426/? E/SoundPool﹕ error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-02 15:54:40.472      381-426/? W/AudioService﹕ Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-02 15:54:40.472      381-426/? E/SoundPool﹕ error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-02 15:54:40.472      381-426/? W/AudioService﹕ Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-02 15:54:40.472      381-426/? E/SoundPool﹕ error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
07-02 15:54:40.472      381-426/? W/AudioService﹕ Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
07-02 15:54:40.472      381-426/? E/SoundPool﹕ error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
07-02 15:54:40.472      381-426/? W/AudioService﹕ Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
07-02 15:54:40.482      381-426/? E/SoundPool﹕ error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
07-02 15:54:40.482      381-426/? W/AudioService﹕ Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
07-02 15:54:40.482      381-426/? E/SoundPool﹕ error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
07-02 15:54:40.492      381-426/? W/AudioService﹕ Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
07-02 15:54:40.492      381-426/? E/SoundPool﹕ error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
07-02 15:54:40.492      381-426/? W/AudioService﹕ Soundpool could not load file: /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
07-02 15:54:40.492      381-426/? W/AudioService﹕ onLoadSoundEffects(), Error -1 while loading samples
07-02 15:54:40.662      536-536/? I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 114 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-02 15:54:41.182      381-632/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Process com.example.scoelli.hello (pid 1696) has died.
07-02 15:54:41.182      381-628/? I/WindowState﹕ WIN DEATH: Window{b3053f60 u0 com.example.scoelli.hello/com.example.scoelli.hello.MyActivity}
07-02 15:54:41.392      381-442/? D/LightsService﹕ Excessive delay setting light: 1438ms
```

Thank You!

Comment: Don't you have access to logcat?

Comment: I do but I'm newbie and don't even know what to look for there.

Comment: Logcat will tell you in which line of your code is the error and you can start debugging from there.

Comment: The URL included in your code doesn't exist. I expect that it's causing your code to throw an exception but your `catch` clause has no code.

Comment: Yeah a logcat would definitely help.

Comment: OK, I will use logcat, the url exist but if you are connected to my network. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app crashes with a NetworkOnMainThreadExeption as you do network access in the main thread. Put your http client code in an AsyncTask or thread and request internet permission in your manifest. The exception will be in your logcat. But you did not post that...

Comment: I'm using AsyncTask now but the app still crashes. I'll edit the question with the code I have now

Comment: In the logcat is a `NullPointerException` caused by code on line `ConnectTask.onPostExecute(MyActivity.java:144)` Which line is that? Double click in the logcat on this line and it will bring you to line 144 in your code. I bed it is this line `StatusLine statusLine = result.getStatusLine();`. With result== null. You have to realise that doInBackground can return response or null. So in onPostExecute you should check result for null and act accordingly.

Answer (score -2):

You need to create an API (REST) in PHP that you call from your app.

Using a library to help handle async callbacks can be super helpful for this.

This is the one I usually use:

[**LoopJ's Async HTTP Callback Library**](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/)

This will handle GET and POST requests with a lot of cool features such as custom timeouts, JSON format, onSuccess() and onFailure() methods, etc. There's a lot of working examples of this library too. I've used it in all my apps and haven't had any problems yet!

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: His question didn't make sense. It's too open ended to "answer" in one sentence. Hes going about it the wrong way and I was trying to point him in the right direction. He needs to create an API. If he doesn't know how to do that, hes welcome to comment on my answer and I'll edit + elaborate.